# Remove empty page before chapter

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I keep getting empty pages and am struggling to remove them. :/

This is the documentclass I am using

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4, headinclude, 
twoside=false, parskip=half+, pagesize=auto, numbers=noenddot, 
plainheadsepline, open=right, toc=listof, toc=bibliography]{scrreprt}
```

After the table of contents I include my *problem-chapter*, a symbol directory. I want it to appear in the toc, but unnumbered, so I put this in the beginning:

```
\chapter*{symbol directory}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{symbol directory}
\markboth{left}{right}
```

Without `\markboth` the header would somehow carry on the header of the previous chapter?

Anyway: Before the content and caption of my symbol directory is displayed, I get the empty page. Thus the content is not starting on the first page of the chapter, but on the second, and I get the header 'right'. Normally the first page of a chapter does not display a header.

Comment: Use the `\addchap` command and for the rest: make a minimal complete example.

Comment: Thanks. I was just about to do that and figured out what is causing the problems: I am creating my symbol directory with tabular and it seems that the table is just one line too large. As soon as I remove one line there is no empty page before it anymore. I will try to play around with the fontsize/spacing of the table.

Comment: Use `longtable` which allows page breaks?